# Error: Access not granted or expired. when accessing Google Admin Directory API via service account and domain wide delegation

Tags: google-apps-script, google-oauth, google-admin-sdk, service-accounts

I am developing a google Apps script which [lists](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/groups/list) all google groups. The App is published with **Execute the app ass user accessing the web app** and **Who has access to the app -> Anyone in specific Domain**. I am using a service account and [Domain Wide Delegation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation) to impersonate a Gsuite admin account in order to access the API.

```
function getDomWideDelegationService(serviceName) { 
 const scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group";
 const email = 'gsuiteAdmin@mydomain.com';

var props = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
const keyfromstore = props.getProperty("SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY");    
   const serviceaccount = props.getProperty("SERVICEACCOUNT");
  return OAuth2.createService(serviceName + email)
  .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')
  .setPrivateKey(keyfromstore)
  .setIssuer(serviceaccount)
  .setSubject(email)
  .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties())
  .setScope(scope);
}
```

and this is the part where I access the google api:

```
function listUsersGroups(user){
const adminMail = 
PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("ADMIN_EMAIL");
var service = getDomWideDelegationService('listGroup:', 
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group',adminMail);
  const token = service.getAccessToken();
  var requestBody                = {};
  requestBody.headers            = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + 
service.getAccessToken()};
requestBody.method             = "GET";
requestBody.muteHttpExceptions = false;

 var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/? 
 userKey='+user;
  var listGroupResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, requestBody);
   var statusCode = listGroupResponse.getResponseCode();
 var contentText = listGroupResponse.getContentText();
 var contentObj = JSON.parse(contentText);

 if(statusCode == 200)
   console.log(`listing groups was successful`);
 else
   console.error(`listing group  was NOT successful with error: 
${contentText}`);
 if(contentObj.hasOwnProperty("groups"))
   return contentObj.groups;
 else
   return [];
   }
```

However I always get:

`Error: Access not granted or expired.`

I double checked following:

- Are the credentials of the service account correct?
- Is the `gsuiteAdmin@mydomain.com` a Gsuite Admin?
- Is the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group` added in the GSuite for the service account? (Security->API Controls->Domain Wide Delegation)
- Is the scope added to the Google Appscript Porject?
- Is the Google Admin Directory API added to the Advanced Google Services of the Apps Script Project?
- Is the Google Admin Directory API added to the GCP Project?

I have no idea what else I could check...

Comment: Does it work if you deploy the WebApp as you?

Comment: No, exact same error. I also made it accessible to everyone. No difference.

Comment: Show the code where you access the group.

Comment: I wish Eric was still active here... I don't see anything wrong with how you use the OAuth2.0 library for GAS here (although you should include that info in the question). One thing you could try - try passing the `scope` as an array to `setScope`.

Comment: @TheMaster, I updated the question. However the problem is not the code since the same code is already working in another gsuite.( with a different service account)

Comment: See if adding the scopes manually to the manifest solves the issue: `"oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group"],`